# Tree tag redirects to Minecraft tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft/synonyms

Apparently [trees](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) redirects to [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

How did this happen? and can we get that removed please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh. I was fairly certain I'd merged that to [minecraft-trees](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-trees), as *all* [tree](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree) questions were also tagged [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), but it appears I got it horribly wrong.

Removed.

By the way, you can see a list of tag synonyms and who created which one when [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)

Comment: I think that's my fault. I merged Minecraft-trees with Minecraft and didn't realize that meant "tree" would, thanks to the transitive property, wind up pointing at minecraft.